# ssh_config AddKeysToAgent yes not working on Fedora

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I've tried a multitude of things to get this working but despite having the AddKeysToAgent variable set to yes in my ssh_config the keys are not getting added.

This is my ssh-config:

```
Host * 
    AddKeysToAgent yes 
Host remote 
    HostName /*hostname for remote here*/
    User dcaglar2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal_laptop
    IdentitiesOnly yes 

Host git 
    HostName github.com
    User git  
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and running

```
ssh-add -l
```

returns

```
The agent has no identites.
```

I've checked the man pages ssh, ssh_config, but wasn't able to find anything.
I know that I can add a line to my .bashrc as a substitute but I just want to know what's wrong at this point.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of `AddKeysToAgent` in the `ssh_config` manual:

> If this option is set to yes and a key is loaded from a file, the key and its passphrase are added to the agent with the default lifetime, as if by ssh-add(1).

If I'm not mistaken, a key will be added to the agent the first time it's used. So try connecting to a remote and then run `ssh-add -l` again, you should then see the corresponding key in the output.